# What is the reason you can't use static methods/variables in a class

Tags: swift, static

I was wondering why you cant use the `static` keyword in a class.
I know that you can use it in a `struct` but not in a `class` 
Does anyone know why they choose for this?
And if so are there any advantages for letting `static` away?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a terminological *bêtise*. What Apple did was decide that you use `static` in an enum or struct and `class` in a class. In my view this was a very foolish decision, as they are exactly parallel to one another. Many people have posted on the dev forums suggesting that they just call them all `static`.

The outcome is a candidate for Occam's Razor: two phrases, e.g. static property and class property, or static method and class method, that mean exactly the same thing. And then they try to cover their tracks in the documentation by adding a third term as an umbrella, "type property" (meaning a static-or-class property) or "type method" (meaning a static-or-class method), which just makes the situation even worse.

The badness of the situation is also revealed by what you have to do in protocols: you declare a `class` property in a protocol and then if a struct adopts it, it calls that a `static` property. Same thing with a `class` method in a protocol; an adopting struct must call that a `static` method. You'd think that this alone would have told them they'd done a bad thing.

**Edit**: The more I think about it, the more I like the proposal put forth by `newacct` in a comment below. If Apple had simply used the umbrella keyword `type` here *as part of the language*, the whole problem would have been solved. We could have declarations `type var`, `type let`, `type func`, and this would work equally in enums, structs, classes, and protocols across the board.

Comment: Up voting purely for bêtise

Comment: What do I get for using _bêtise_ and Occam's Razor in the same post?? I'm looking up the street for the MacArthur Genius Grant truck but it doesn't seem to be coming! :)

Comment: "static property and class property, or static method and class method, that mean exactly the same thing" They do not mean the same thing. For calls to static methods and static properties, which method is called is always determined *statically* (i.e. it is fixed at compile-time). On the other hand, there is *dynamic* lookup (which method is called is determined at runtime) for class methods and class properties.

Comment: @newacct Nice to hear from you - always interesting distinctions as usual. But can't we say that MyStruct.myprop and MyClass.myprop are the "the same thing" in some sense? Do we really need two names for these two entities?

Comment: @matt: Yes, they are both type properties. So if we used the keyword `type` for both then I would be fine with it. But not `static`.

Comment: @newacct This is sad - you are taking Apple's side against me! :(

Comment: @matt: Well, I have this pet peeve when people new to Objective-C coming from C++ or Java say "static method" when talking about Objective-C because although it is indeed static in C++/Java, it is not in Objective-C, since unlike C++/Java, "class methods" in Objective-C are inherited and can be called using a class object computed dynamically at runtime. The exact same applies to Swift. If we used the keyword `static`, it would perpetuate this misconception.

Comment: @newacct I've decided I like your keyword `type` idea so much that I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Swift Language Guide on Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_363), Apple has chosen to differentiate the syntax used, based upon the fundamental Type that you're building.

Classes declare "Type Methods" with the keyword `Class`.  Example:

```
class MyClass {
    class func myFunc(){ ... }
}
```

Structs declare "Type Methods" with the keyword `Static`.  Example:

```
struct MyStruct {
    static func myFunc(){ ... }
}
```

In both cases, crating a Type Method allows you to invoke the method without first creating an instance of the class or struct.

Whereas a non class/static function would require something like

```
let instance = MyClass()
instance.myFunc()
```

... declaring the variable as a *Type Method* allows something like
`MyClass.myFunc()`